# With OS login, how to gcloud ssh from one GCE into another GCE?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have two GCEs, both has OS login enabled:

1) a_vm provisioned with service account a_svc

2) b_vm provisioned with service account b_svc

a_svc has OS login access to b_vm.
a_svc has roles/compute.osAdminLogin at project level and roles/iam.serviceAccountUser at b_svc level.

What I tried:

- Ssh into a_vm and `gcloud compute ssh a_vm`, then `gcloud compute ssh b_vm`

What happened:

It times out consistently.
Requests gcloud made before it hangs based on `--log-http`:

```
uri: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/a_svc@fredzqm-terraform-5.iam.gserviceaccount.com/?recursive=True
uri: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/ca_svc@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com/token
uri: https://compute.googleapis.com/batch/compute/v1
uri: https://compute.googleapis.com/batch/compute/v1
uri: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/a_svc@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com/?recursive=True
uri: https://oslogin.googleapis.com/v1/users/a_svc@my_project.gserviceaccount.com/loginProfile?projectId=fredzqm-terraform-5&alt=json
```

What I expects:

Based on https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sa_ssh_manual, gcloud should pick up the default application credential (a_svc) and use it to get access to b_vm through OS login.

What works:

- I have verified that a_svc does have ssh access to b_vm. This works from my workstation using personal creds:

  `gcloud compute ssh b_vm --impersonate-service-account a_svc`
- If I add a ssh public key to a_svc, and then use the public key to ssh into `b_vm`.

  `gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file`

  `ssh sa_<id_of_a_svc>@b_vm -i private_key_path`

Comment: Please clarify your sentence "a_svc has roles/compute.osAdminLogin at project level and roles/iam.serviceAccountUser at b_svc level." and also "Ssh into a_vm and gcloud compute ssh b_vm, then gcloud compute ssh b_vm". What does " at b_svc level." mean?  Why did you ssh to to b_vm and then to b_vm again?

Comment: In addition, please share your commands and outputs to make me able to check them on my test project.

Comment: Try to grant role `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` to service account `a_svc` and you should be able to connect from `a_vm` to `b_vm` as you expected.

Comment: Sorry I meant for ssh into a_vm and then into b_vm. a_svc already has roles/iam.serviceAccountUser for b_svc as shown in "what works" section, other means are working already. I am a bit surprised that gcloud ssh did not work

Comment: I've tried to follow your steps and I was able to connect to `a_vm` with my account and then connect from `a_vm` to `b_vm` **without** copying ssh key into `a_vm` with command `gcloud compute ssh b_vm`. I'll share my steps tomorrow.

Comment: I boostraped another project with the same set up with terraform, so they are consistent. However, I was not able to reproduce this issue. Quite odd. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your issue and failed. I was able to connect to `service-account-b-instance` from `service_account_a_instance` as the service account and execute commands as that service account.

Have a look at my steps below:

1. create service account `service_account_a`
2. create VM instance associated with `service_account_a_instance`:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances create service-account-a-instance --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --service-account=service-account-a@test-prj.iam.gserviceaccount.com --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE

   Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/service-account-a-instance].
   NAME                        ZONE            MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
   service-account-a-instance  europe-west3-a  n1-standard-1               10.156.0.14  35.XXX.75.XXX  RUNNING
   ```
3. create service account `service_account_b`
4. create VM instance `service_account_b_instance` associated with `service_account_b`:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances create service-account-b-instance --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --service-account=service-account-b@test-prj.iam.gserviceaccount.com --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE

   Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/service-account-b-instance].
   NAME                        ZONE            MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
   service-account-b-instance  europe-west3-a  n1-standard-1               10.156.0.16  35.XXX.255.XXX  RUNNING
   ```
5. generate ssh keys:

   ```
   $ ssh-keygen
   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   ```
6. import ssh key:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file id_rsa.pub
   ```
7. connect to instance `service-account-a-instance`:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute ssh service-account-a-instance
   Linux service-account-a-instance 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1 (2020-01-20) x86_64

   The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
   the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
   individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

   Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
   permitted by applicable law.
   Last login: Mon Mar  2 14:34:51 2020 from 104.132.189.65
   user_domain_com@service-account-a-instance:~$
   ```
8. connect to instance `service-account-b-instance` from `service-account-a-instance`:

   ```
   user_domain_com@service-account-a-instance:~$ gcloud compute ssh service-account-b-instance --project test-prj --zone europe-west3-a

   ...

   ssh: connect to host 35.242.255.44 port 22: Connection timed out
   ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
   ```
9. enable ssh connectivity at `VPC network` -> `Firewall` and try again:

   ```
   user_domain_com@service-account-a-instance:~$ gcloud compute ssh service-account-b-instance --project test-prj --zone europe-west3-a
   Permission denied (publickey).
   ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
   ```
10. add role `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` to `service-account-a` and try again:

    ```
    user_domain_com@service-account-a-instance:~$ gcloud compute ssh service-account-b-instance --project test-prj --zone europe-west3-a

    Linux service-account-b-instance 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1 (2020-01-20) x86_64

    The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
    the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
    individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

    Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
    permitted by applicable law.
    Last login: Mon Mar  2 16:52:28 2020 from 35.198.75.226
    sa_116762935227008431464@service-account-b-instance:~$
    sa_116762935227008431464@service-account-b-instance:~$ uname -a
    Linux service-account-b-instance 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1 (2020-01-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
    ```

    and finally it works.

Comment: I tried this between prod and staging GCE instances and I am still getting "sa_XXXX@IP-ADDRESS: Permission denied (publickey)."